# How on earth do I get iTunes to play an album?

Tags: itunes, album

I tried the old right click and select play on the drop down menu trick. Which didn't work.

Now I'm fresh out of ideas.

I'm using Vista Home and iTunes 12.0.1.26.

Answer (score 1):

1. On iTunes set to Music, on the top-right corner, select "Albums".

[image]

2. Choose the album you want to play.
3. Press the "play" button on the screen it will open. This will reproduce the entire album's songs.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work on my pc. I would have thought it would but no. My wife said that she found that her iTunes went crazy if she didn't update it, so maybe that's my problem. I don't see why it would be though, if I'm not updating anything else and it used to work fine. The only thing I can think of is that Apple is telling my iTunes to crap itself so that I'll update it.

Comment: Which I find quite disgusting. I already hate Macs as it is, since I can't use them and this is just another reason to hate apple, if it is actually the case.